# Ошибка получения сообщений в чате на python

Tags: python, многопоточность, сокет, chat, threading

подскажите, почему в поле ввода сообщения клиентского чата, выводится сообщение от других участников, а само поле ввода не переносится?
Сейчас это выглядит так:

```
Enter your message:: You are connected!
*hello*
```

Но я хочу получить такой результат:

```
You are connected!
Enter your message:: *hello*
```

А после отправки сообщения, чтобы сообщение отправленное клиентом, как и поле ввода для нового сообщения, начинались с новой строки:

```
*hello*
Enter your message::
```

Я понимаю, что функция input ждет, когда клиент введет сообщение и в это же время в чат клиента прилетает сообщение от другого клиента, и программе ничего не остается на вывести это новое сообщение в поле ввода. Так вот как распределить сообщения и действия с ними на новой строке?
Сервер:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(("127.0.0.1", 1234))

server.listen(20)
print("server is listening...")

users = []

def send_all(data): 
    for user in users:
        user.send(data) 

def listen_user(user_socket): 
    while True:
        data = user_socket.recv(2048) 
        print(f"User send: {data}")
        send_all(data) 

def start_server():
    while True: 
        user_socket, address = server.accept() 
        print(f"User {address[1]} connected.")

        user_socket.send("You are connected!".encode("utf-8"))
        users.append(user_socket)

        listen_send_user = Thread(target=listen_user, args=(user_socket,)) 
        listen_send_user.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server()
```

Клиент:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("127.0.0.1", 1234))

def listen_server():
    while True:
        data = client.recv(2048)
        print(data.decode('utf-8'))

def send_server():
    listen_thread_server = Thread(target=listen_server)
    listen_thread_server.start()
    while True:
        client.send(input("Enter your message:: ").encode("utf-8"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_server()
```

Comment: Вероятно, вы хотите поделить экран на несколько областей. В одной области показывать входящие сообщения, в другой ввод от пользователя. Т.е. вам нужно реализовать пользовательский интерфейс с поддержкой (может упрощенных) компонентов. Тут пригодятся библиотеки типа https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/curses.html или http://urwid.org/ или [другие того же типа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41785267/2231972)

Comment: @RomanKonoval Не совсем то, что я имел в виду, грубо говоря, я хотел бы, чтобы каждое сообщение от других клиентов начиналось с новой строки, а не залезало на поле ввода текущего. И я хотел бы добиться этого в одном терминальном окне клиента, не создавая никаких областей. В целом, мне удалось это сделать, если в input убрать подсказку "Enter your message:: ", то каждые сообщения, которые приходят от других юзеров, всегда будут находиться выше, чем поле ввода. Не знаю как это объяснить, но это сработало, и спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Не уверен, что это решит вашу проблему даже если убирать подсказку ввода. Начал пользователь вводить сообщение, ввел первое слово, оно уже показано на экране, а тут приходит новое сообщение. Как вы себе представляете поведение программы в этом случае без разделения экрана на области? В терминале вывод и ввод текста происходит в позиции курсора. Т.е. чтоб пользователь мог продолжить ввод текста, а при этом сообщение показывалось, курсор нужно перемещать между двумя областями (не обязательно явно, это может сделать библиотека, но суть от этого не меняется)